# How to infer conditional generic type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How to infer conditional generic type in constructor?

In example below TS can't infer the `new Hash({ a: 1, b: 2 })` and requires explicit type specification `new Hash<string, number>({ a: 1, b: 2 })`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEASkAsA8BpANNAagPmgbwChpoB9ASwFsAHEaAXmgDsBTAd2gFkwrUMcAKAJQEi0YAHtGEAC4AnAK7Bp42UNESpcxctVlpzChABc0fimjMAHvsYATGDNllGAc2gB+fNADaAa2YAniaOzi4AuiaY0AC+0AA+0PJ2zABmzsy20CZJtqnptoLCxBqO2ir8egYQ7iYASswSsrZIIa582IL4osRkKaaVhp0pKqYgzNLQvtDO0-qD0NIIZBAAdOTUICsQ4-xTkNBgjAEYAxB+YUUxIsTb0rsm6NAAbpGdeNEEHwQlEwgAjPQmGw4IgWnJQhhGPIKAAjZiybD8PAHEx-DAwkwAJhinQA9LjoAB1FS+GCsPQICyWGhkYB6Aj-LY7ADkYGZGD+wm+khk0AQ2IYLHY8AgCCRKOgaOgGOg2OieIJABFxMwIIxmRNWCSMAAVADKYkOGumjBS8IZmKZd1Z7MlXJ+fIAzIChSDRUgobD4ZDoXCEWoEI6rfwpZygA)

```
class Hash<K, V> {
  _impl = new Map<K, V>()

  constructor()
  constructor(items: (K extends string ? { [key: string]: V } | undefined : undefined))
  constructor(items?: Record<string, V>) {
    if (items) for (let k in items) this._impl.set(k as any, items[k])
  }

  set(k: K, v: V) {}
}

const h1 = new Hash<string, number>({ a: 1, b: 2 }) // Works
h1.set('a', 1)

const h2 = new Hash({ a: 1, b: 2 }) // Doesn't work, TS can't infer
h2.set('a', 1)

const h3 = new Hash<number, number>() // Works

const h4 = new Hash<string, number>() // Works
```

P.S.

A possible workaround suggested by @jcalz to use helper. I'm leaving the original question, as maybe there are other ways to solve it.

```
function H<V>(items: Record<string, V>): Hash<string, V>
function H<K, V>(items: [K, V][]): Hash<K, V>
function H<K, V>(items: Record<string, V> | [K, V][]): Hash<any, V> {
  if (items instanceof Array) return new Hash(items)
  else                        return new Hash(items)
}

H({ a: 1, b: 2 })

H([[1, 1], [2, 2]])
```

Comment: Hm, using defaults works: `class Hash<K = string, V = never> { … }`. I also played with `constructor(items: Record<K extends string ? string : never, V> | void)` (but that doesn't prevent passing objects with non-`never` keys when `K` is not string) and `constructor(items: Record<string, K extends string ? V : never> | void)` (which seems nicer, but doesn't support inference either).

Comment: What's the intent here? If I call `new Hash({a: 1, b: 2})`, that means `K extends string ? {[key: string]: V} | undefined` is of type `{a: 1, b: 2}`.  Presumably that means `V` is `number` (or maybe `1 | 2` or something), but how would we compute `K`?  Using deductive reasoning one could conclude that `K` might be any type that's a union of any subtype of `string` with anything else (e.g., `"foo" | 7` will work).  And the compiler isn't as smart as a person, so it just gives up.  So that's why it doesn't work.  To fix it I would strongly recommend refactoring away from this.

Comment: Are you answering your own question? Then you should probably make it an answer and not a question edit.  Or... are you changing the question somehow?  Then please clarify what you're asking about now (are you still asking the original question?)  how should we proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz sorry for inconvenience, and thanks for advice I followed your advice about refactoring and introduced the `H` helper. I leaved the initial question open as maybe there's some way to make it work. I updated the post and mentioned your solution.